# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'

Tags: typescript

me sale error al colocar ':' al inspeccionar en typescript
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: A qué le estás intentando asingar el  `:any`, nombre o poder?? No pongas el `any`directamente y no pasa nada. Pero si vas a ponerlo, tendrás que declarar el tipo de ambas variables: `nombre: any, poder: any`

Comment: independientemente del código si pongo los dos puntos me arroja ese error

Comment: Es que no puedes poner dos puntos después de los corchetes... no estás tipando los corchetes, si no las variables dentro

Comment: creo que lo que quieres es tipar la function arrow, para eso debes colocarlo despues de los paréntesis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No conozco cuál es el objetivo de esa porción de código, pero porqué no intentas poniendo lo mismo de otra forma?

```
const extraer = (nombre = avenger.nombre, poder = avenger.poder) => {
console.log(nombre);
console.log(poder);
}
```

Comment: extraer(); //para correr el código